# How to align 2 objects in Blender using 3 or more points as landmarks

Tags: modeling

I want to align 2 scans of same object according to select landmarks in such a way that their orientation and location would be the same for scan purposes. Can someone please help, if anyone can create a script that would be super helpful.
Thank you!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6369/how-to-align-an-object-by-one-or-two-edges-to-xyz-axes https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/156787/how-can-i-align-a-model-to-three-custom-points-with-a-python-script